# Proving uniqueness in naive set theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I am doing the following exercise from Velleman's How To Prove It:

Prove that there is a unique $A \in \mathcal P (U)$ such that for every $ B\in \mathcal P (U)$, $A \cup B=A$. ($ \mathcal P (U)$ being the powerset of U)

One solution I found is as follows:

To prove the existence, try $A=U$. For any $ B\in \mathcal P (U)$, $B\subseteq U$ and so $U\cup B=U$.

To prove the uniqueness, let say there is another set $ C\in \mathcal P (U)$ s.t. $\forall B \in \mathcal P (U)(C \cup B=C)$. We can put $B=U \setminus C$ in this equation to get $C \cup (U \setminus C) =C$, therefore $U=C$ and hence $C=U=A$.

Two confusions I have:

1. I understand the existence proof, but how could you know you should substitute $U$ for $A$? Is it just by practice and experience?
2. I do not understand what's going on in the uniqueness proof at all. In the preceding pages the following existence and uniqueness form have been mentioned:

a. $\exists x(Fx \land \forall y(Fy \to y=x) $

b. $\exists x \forall y(Fy$↔$y=x)$

c. $\exists x Fx \land \forall y \forall z ((Fy \land Fz) \to y=z)  $

But none of these seem to fit into what he is trying to do here. I don't understand where is the $ C\in \mathcal P (U)$ from; it seems that he did an existential instantiation but it is not apparent to me where the existential comes from.

More importantly, why substitute $B$ (instead of $A$) for $B=U \setminus C$? And wouldn't $B=U \setminus C$ be contradictory to the conclusion? Since if we substitute $B$ with this from $(C \cup B=C)$, it becomes $x\in C \lor (x \in U \land \sim x \in C)=x \in C$. If we try to prove this by cases, the second case i.e. second disjunction would yield the negated form of the conclusion: $\sim x \in C$!

Could anyone please help me on this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Your exercise is to prove about intersection but the proof is about union?

Comment: Thank you, should be ok now

Comment: Well, there is a simpler uniqueness argument which uses commutativity: if you have two such sets, say $A$ and $A'$, then $$A= A \cup A' = A' \cup A = A'$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first question:If you think about the property that such $A\in \mathcal{P}$ should satisfy, it is:

> **$(\star)$  For each $B\in\mathcal{P}(U)$, $A\cup B=A$. **

So, such $A$ is a subset of $U$, and since $A\cup B=A$ iff $B\subseteq A$, we have that such $A$ is actually *the largest subset of $U$*. This gives you some intuition of why $A$ should be equal to $U$.

For the second question: I don't see clearly why the intersections become unions in your argument, so I take the opportunity to change it a little bit:

> **Goal**: Prove that if $C$ satisfy the required condition, then $C=U$.

First of all, we know that $C\in \mathcal{P}(U)$, so $C\subseteq U$. On the other hand, if we put $B=U\setminus C$, then by the condition $(\star)$ we have

$$C=B\cup C=(U\setminus C) \cup C$$ and so, $U\setminus C\subseteq C$. This is only possible if $U\setminus C=\emptyset$, or equivalent, if $U\subseteq C$.

This shows that $C=U$, by double contenence.

Comment: Thank you so much for your follow up, but I still don't understand: 1. does knowing A∪B=A iff B⊆A come with experience? Because I had to do the proof to know this? 2. How did you know A is the largest subset of U? Supposedly the largest subset of any set (U) is itself (in this case, A), but didn't that already assume A=U, which was what we hoped to know?

Comment: @DanielMak For the first question, note that for any sets $A,B$, it is true that $B\subseteq A\cup B$. So $A\cup B=A$ immediately leads to $B\subseteq A$. On the other hand, if $A$ satisfies the required property, then $A$ is a subset of $U$ and for all $B\subseteq U$ we will also have (by the previous part) that $B\subseteq A$. This only gives you the intuition that the required set will be $A=U$, but  you will have to prove that $A=U$ indeed satisfies the required property (I did not do it, but it is easy).  What I did from that point to the end was prove uniqueness

Comment: 'if A satisfies the required property, then A is a subset of U' But we were given A∈P(U), so surely we can simply assume A⊆U, instead of going through that thinking process? (It is also not clear to me how A satisfying the said property will entail A⊆U?)

Comment: @DanielMak The most important part of the sentence you were quoting is the part that you omitted. The desired property is: "$X\in \mathcal{P}(U)$ and for all $B\in \mathcal{P}(U)$, $X\cup B=X$".

Comment: Sorry I have one last question: I understand that, since we have established A∪B=A, we could instantiate A to C to get C=B∪C=(U∖C)∪C. But I don't understand how does U∖C⊆C follow from this. In particular, you mentioned, 'This is only possible if U∖C=∅, or equivalent, if U⊆C.' I get how it is only possible if U∖C=∅ (because otherwise x∈U∧∼x∈C contradicts the conclusion x∈C), but how does that imply U⊆C?

I understand these may look like stupid questions, but as someone who is not enrolled in uni, I cannot emphasize enough how great these supports are, thank you so much!

Comment: @DanielMak First, note that for any sets $X,Y$ we have $X\subseteq X\cup Y$. (Can you show why?). That explains why $U\setminus C\subseteq (U\setminus C)\cup C$, and the last is equal to $C$ by the hypothesis. [$C$ satisfies the desired property]

Comment: @DanielMak Now, note that $U\setminus C=\emptyset \Leftrightarrow \neg   \exists x(x\in U \wedge x\not\in C)$ and this is equivalent to                   $\forall x(x\in C\rightarrow x\in U)\Leftrightarrow C\subseteq U$

Comment: Thank you so much! Now that I have reviewed everything you wrote they all fall in place nicely, I guess I was panicking so I couldn't understand some of the explanation, I can't believe I was stuck at B⊆A∪B=A and B⊆A.

I am truly grateful for your patience in explaining this to me, thank you so much again!

Comment: @DanielMak No problem!

Comment: Sorry I have one last-last question, how do I decide what to substitute for B in the uniqueness proof (in this case, U∖C)? I want to know because I want to understand the rationale and be able to do similar exercises independently

Comment: I am afraid there is no simple answer for that question. I guess $U\setminus C$ was the "natural substitution" in this case because we had in mind that $C$ was going to be equal to $U$, so we try in both cases (in the answer and in the "answer below") to prove that $U\setminus C=\emptyset$. In a more general setting, I think it highly depends on the kind of property we want to prove, and on the candidate we have in mind.

Comment: Thank you! That has already given me a general direction at least

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first question:If you think about the property that such $A\in \mathcal{P}$ should satisfy, it is:

> **$(\star)$  For each $B\in\mathcal{P}(U)$, $A\cap B=B$. **

So, such $A$ is a subset of $U$, and since $A\cap B=B$ iff $B\subseteq A$, we have that such $A$ is actually *the largest subset of $U$*. This gives you some intuition of why $A$ should be equal to $U$.

For the second question: I don't see clearly why the intersections become unions in your argument, so I take the opportunity to change it a little bit:

> **Goal**: Prove that if $C$ satisfy the required condition, then $C=U$.

First of all, we know that $C\in \mathcal{P}(U)$, so $C\subseteq U$. On the other hand, if we put $B=U\setminus C$, then by the condition $(\star)$ we have

$$U\setminus C=B=B\cap C=(U\setminus C) \cap C=\emptyset$$ and so, $U\subseteq C$ (because we knew already that $C\subseteq U$).

This shows that $C=U$, by double contenence.

Comment: I am terribly sorry about this; I made a typo when I first typed this question up so that the conclusion I need to reach is actually supposed to be A∪B=A instead of A∩B=B.
So sorry about this

Comment: @DanielMak If you understood the argument above, I am sure that you can reconstruct the proof that you need. Note that $A\cup B=A$ if and only if $B\subseteq A$.